# Fancy Reverse Syntax for If and For Statements

Tags: python

I often see code similar to this:

```
return [(var, val) for val in self.domains[var]
                    if self.nconflicts(var, val, assignment) == 0]
```

and I'm like DAMN that's sexy. But then I try to drop it sometimes and I get syntax errors. Are there any particular rules for this nice form of code writing that reverses  the typical placement of `for` and `if` statements?

Comment: List comprehensions are pretty awesome. There are also dictionary and set comprehensions, alongside generator expressions. I have [a video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY&list=UUAuqj5Bs5mTTl1mIVDmuAlw&index=1&feature=plcp) you can watch which explains them a little.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're called [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). The basic syntax is (I'm using parens to group my words, not as part of the syntax):

```
[(an expression involving x) for x in someList if (some condition)]
```

If the `condition` evaluates to true, the resulting list includes the `(expression involving x)`. So, for example, the following list comprehension uses this to only include strings in the resulting list.

```
>>> myList = [1,"hello",5.4,"world"]
>>> [elem for elem in myList if type(elem)==str]
['hello', 'world']
```

Note that the `if` part is optional, and the `expression involving x` can be as simple as just `x` (often used when you are just filtering out elements from another list).

In fact, the `expression involving x` doesn't really have to have `x` in it at all. For example, if for some reason you wanted a list of `0`'s as long as your name you could do this:

```
>>> [0 for letter in "Matthew"]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

For when you don't need the list to stick around after you make it, use [generator expressions](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) instead. (Generator expressions and list comprehensions have the same syntax.)

Answer (score 2):

See [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in the Python tutorial documentation. There are quite a number of things you can do with this syntax, including creating lists, sets, and dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

The concept is called list comprehension,

http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk

Take a look at lambda functions too,

http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk

Answer (score 2):

Although your example code is indeed a list comprehension, you do also occasionally see the reverse if syntax for inline conditionals:

```
a if b else c
```